# I need to write a bulkify trigger for this trigger how should i regret as bulkify for this?

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

```
trigger objAobjBnameaddedinobjC on Object_C__c (before insert) {
  for(Object_C__c c : trigger.new)
  {
    Object_A__c a;
    Object_B__c b;
    a = [select id, name, Type__c from Object_A__c where id = :c.Object_A__c];
    b = [select id, name, Type__c from Object_B__c where id = :c.Object_B__c];
    if(a.Type__c == b.Type__c)
      c.name += a.name + b.name; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: you don't seem to be changing any data here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard aggregate-query-update pattern. Here's one possible implementation:

```
trigger objAObjBNameAddedInObjC on Object_C__c (before insert) {
    // Maps store a key and a value, like a dictionary holds words and their definitions
    Map<Id, Object_A__c> a = new Map<Id, Object_A__c>();
    Map<Id, Object_B__c> b = new Map<Id, Object_B__c>();
    // Aggregate the data we need to query
    for(Object_C__c record: Trigger.new) {
        a.put(record.Object_A__c, null);
        b.put(record.Object_B__c, null);
    }
    // Query the data we would like to get
    a.putAll([SELECT Id, Name, Type__c FROM Object_A__c WHERE Id IN :a.keySet()]);
    b.putAll([SELECT Id, Name, Type__c FROM Object_B__c WHERE Id IN :b.keySet()]);
    // Update object C when the conditions are met
    for(Object_C__c record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Object_A__c != null && record.Object_B__c != null && a.get(record.Object_A__c).Type__c == b.get(record.Object_B__c).Type__c) {
            c.Name = a.get(record.Object_A__c).Name+b.get(record.Object_B__c).Name;
        }
    }
}
```